# Button onclick does not working in reactJS with below code

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, buttonclick

```
const [open, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const openForm = () => setIsOpen(true);
    <button class="openButton"  onClick={() => {openForm}} style={openButton}>Chat</button>        
        <div class="chatPopup" id="myForm"  style={chatPopup}>
        <Form open={open}/>
          <div class="formContainer" style={formContainer}>
            <span class="title1" style={title1}>Chat</span>
            <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>                                         
           <iframe customFrameSection  style={customFrameSection} frameborder="1" id="AIChat" style={{border:'1px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.3)',width: "285px",height: "400px"}}></iframe>
           <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick={closeForm} style={cancelButton}>Close</button>
          </div>
          </div>
```

I have tried multiple ways,onclick should open chat window,how chat popup with id myform will open,is am missing to give myform id anywhere,Please sugest me ,what am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to changing onClick to be `onClick={openForm}`, check your HTML code.

```
 <Form open={open}/>
```

I don't see the content in the Form. Maybe you meant this?

```
<From open={open}>
 <div class="formContainer" style={formContainer}>
    <span class="title1" style={title1}>Chat</span>
    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>                                         
     ....
 </div>      
</Form>
```

Comment: I tried this aswell but no result, in Console i have got warning like Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onSubmit` is marked as required in `Form`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Form (created by HomePage) is this any browser issue or something

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the whole code. As the warning says, you may pass in the prop `onSubmit` as it's required. like `<Form open={open} onSubmit={someAction}></Form>`. But it's not the breaker, likely the `<Form>` component does not check `open` correctly. Are you able to past your `<Form>` component?

Comment: I think problem is my chatpopup default style is display : none with document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block"; this code form is getting open correctly.but with <Form open={open}> it is not opening,const chatPopup = {
    display: "none",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "75px",
    right: "15px",
    border: '3px solid #F1F1F1',
    zIndex:9
  };

Comment: const chatPopup = {
    display: "none",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "75px",
    right: "15px",
    border: '3px solid #F1F1F1',
    zIndex:9
  };
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={openForm} style={openButton} >IRB Chat</Button>  
      <Form open={open}>
    <div class="chatPopup" id= "myForm" style={chatPopup}>
      <div class="formContainer" style={formContainer}>                                     
       <iframe customFrameSection  style={customFrameSection} frameborder="1" id="AIChat" ></iframe>
      </div>      
  </div>
      </Form>

Comment: okay. You know `{open}` is just a prop, and its value is either true or false and it will not open or close the form magically, You need to assign the logic to it. As I see from your comments, you may create another style like chatPopupOpen={display: "block" ...}, and then do this: `<div class="chatPopup" id= "myForm" style={open ? chatPopupOpen : chatPopup}> ` if you don't really use `open` props in your `Form` component.

Answer (score 0):

You're providing Anonymous function to onClick listener which is doing nothing, either call clickForm function there or pass its reference there in onClick like -

```
const [open, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const openForm = () => setIsOpen(true);
<button class="openButton"  onClick={openForm} style={openButton}>Chat</button>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but dint worked .
<button class="openButton"  onClick={openForm} style={openButton}>Chat</button>

Answer (score 0):

You are self closing the form tag, and so there is nothing to be opened when the user clicks *Chat*

Wrap your form contents inside the `form` tag and the error will probably be gone!